# Warning: assignment to `u_long' from `unsigned int ****' lacks a cast

Tags: c++

Код:

```
#include "winsock.h"
#include "conio.h"

WSADATA ws;
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
hostent *d_addr;
char text[1024];

int main()
{
    if (FAILED(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &ws))) {
        printf("Error in WSAStartup(...)n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (INVALID_SOCKET == (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {

        printf("Error in socket(...)n");
        return 1;
    }

    d_addr = gethostbyname("smtp.yandex.ru");
    if (d_addr == NULL) {
        printf("Error in gethostbyname(...)n");
        return 1;
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned *****) d_addr->h_addr);
    addr.sin_port = htons(25);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == (connect(s, (sockaddr *) & addr, sizeof(addr)))) {
        printf("Error in connect(...)n");
        return 1;
    }

    recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0);
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    printf("%s", "h_name");
    printf("Press any keyn");
    getch();
}
```

Я только начинаю изучать с++, хочу написать программу которая будет подключаться к эл. почте напрямую, пока остановился на подключении, не могу занести параметр с IP.

При компиляции пишет

> `In function 'int main()': 43: warning: assignment to 'u_long' from 'unsigned int ****' lacks a cast`

Я так понимаю, что неподписанному интервалу не хватает памяти? Буду благодарен, если кто-то сможет подробно объяснить строчку

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned **** *) d_addr->h_addr);
```

Если её убрать, то при работе в консоли выдается сообщение

> `recv - 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 0.0.0.0 <0.0.0.0:25>, connect error 100 49`

Хочу вывести данные полученные через

```
d_addr = gethostbyname ("smtp.yandex.ru")
```

Но выдается h_name, т.е. просто строка.

Comment: Приведите всё к нормальному виду! Невозможно читать!

Answer (score 2):

А какие полученные данные вы хотите вывести ?
Что бы подключиться, вам нужно иметь заполненную структуру sockaddr_in, и в этой структуре кроме всего прочего должен присутствовать адрес назначения .sin_addr.s_addr, network byte адрес а не IP или там почтовый например!!! 
функция gethostbyname позволяет получить информацию о хосте по его DNS имени, возвращает она указатель на hostent, у hostent есть матрица адресов h_addr_list тип у нее char , так вот что бы заполнить sin_addr нужно привести их к одному типу ((unsigned long *)&addr.sin_addr) и первое значение [0] (оно же s_addr) заполнить первым значением из матрице адресов ((unsigned long* *)smtpServer->h_addr_list)[0][0], почитайте про указатели и вам станет понятно почему это выглядит так

```
//Объявляем указатель на addr.sin_addr
IN_ADDR* inSinAdrPtr = &addr.sin_addr;

//Преабразовываем IN_ADDR в unsigned long
//Теперь можно обратится к первому элементу 
//как в обычном массиве SinAdrArrayPtr[ x ]
unsigned long * SinAdrArrayPtr = (unsigned long *)inSinAdrPtr;

//Преабразовываем h_addr_list из char** в unsigned long**
unsigned long ** AdrListMatrixPtr = (unsigned long **)smtpServer->h_addr_list;

//и тут уже совсем все стало просто!
SinAdrArrayPtr[0] = AdrListMatrixPtr[0][0];
```

Ну или можно все это одной строкой написать=)

```
((unsigned long *)&addr.sin_addr)[0] =
            ((unsigned long **)smtpServer->h_addr_list)[0][0];
```

Вроде как то так, но возможно что то неправильно сказал, почитайте мсдн.

От делать нечего написал небольшой примерчик, далеко не лучший, но более ли менее рабочий=)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

bool SendSMTPCommand(SOCKET sock, const char* data, char* recvBuffer, int bufferSize);
void base64_encode(char *out, const char *data, unsigned int len);

const char messageFormat[] =
    "from: %s\r\n"
    "to: %s\r\n"
    "subject: %s\r\n\r\n"
    "%s\r\n.";

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    if (argc != 7)
    {
        printf( 
"Please launch with parametrs:\n "
"[file name] [Server] [Login] [Password] [Recipient] [Subject] [Message]\n"
"For example : \nClientSMTP.exe smtp.yandex.ru MyMailBox@yandex.ru 12345 FriendMailBox@mail.ru \"Hi, how are you ?\" \"Please, talk to me!=)\"\r\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //для удобства объявим по указателю на каждый параметр
    const char* server = argv[1];
    const char* login = argv[2];
    const char* pass = argv[3];
    const char* rcpt = argv[4];
    const char* subject = argv[5];
    const char* message = argv[6];

    //Инициализируем библиотеку, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО!!! (см. msdn)
    WSADATA w;
    int error = WSAStartup (0x0202, &w);

    if (error != 0) {
        printf("Error load WinSock library.\nError code #%d\n", error);
        return 1;
    }
    if (w.wVersion != 0x0202) {
        printf("Error WinSock library version.\n");     
        WSACleanup ();
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons( 25 );    //Порт по умолчанию для SMTP сервера

    HOSTENT* smtpServer = gethostbyname(server);
    if (!smtpServer) 
    {
        printf("SMTP server is not available.\n");
        WSACleanup ();
        return 0;
    }

    //unsigned означает что тип беззнаковый,
    //у вас же вообще тип не указан, по этому и ошибка!
    ((unsigned long *)&addr.sin_addr)[0] =
            ((unsigned long **)smtpServer->h_addr_list)[0][0];

    //создаем сокет
    SOCKET sSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Create socket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup ();
        return 0;
    }

    //подключаемся
    error = connect(sSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Connect failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        closesocket(sSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    const int bufSize = 1024;
    char buffer[bufSize + 1];

    //после подключения сервер нам представляется
    //так что нужно обязательно его послушать!
    error = recv (sSocket, buffer, bufSize, 0);
    if (error <= 0)
    {
        printf("Receives error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    buffer[error] = 0;  //не забываем про завершающий строку ноль
    printf("Recv: %s", buffer);

    //вот дальше я не уверен, нужно ли после EHLO домен приписывать
    //с синтаксисом SMTP команд не особо знаком
    //но в нагугленных примерах везде дописывали, и я дописал=)

    //отдельный указатель на login по тому что будем менять адрес
    const char* domain = login;

    do {        
        //проверяем не равен ли первый символ собаке 
        //и потом сдвигаем начало на следующий символ
        if (*domain++ == '@')
            //если равен @ выходим, domain содержит то что нужно!
            break; 
    } while (*domain); //проверяем пока не дошли до конца строки

    sprintf(buffer, "EHLO %s", domain);
    //отправляем EHLO yandex.ru
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize)) 
        return 1;

    //отправляем AUTH LOGIN
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, "AUTH LOGIN", buffer, bufSize)) 
        return 1;

    //если код ответа 334 значит 
    //сервер поддерживает AUTH LOGIN
    //и хочет что бы мы послали ему логин
    //334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
    buffer[3] = 0;
    if (atoi(buffer) != 334)    
    {       
        send(sSocket, "QUIT", 4, 0);
        closesocket(sSocket);
        WSACleanup ();
        return 1;
    }

    //кодируем и отправляем логин
    base64_encode(buffer, login, strlen(login)); 
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize)) 
        return 1;

    //кодируем и отправляем пароль
    base64_encode(buffer, pass, strlen(pass));
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize))
        return 1;

    //проверяем успешно ли авторизовались
    buffer[3] = 0;
    if (atoi(buffer) != 235)
    {       
        send(sSocket, "QUIT", 4, 0);
        closesocket(sSocket);
        WSACleanup ();
        return 1;
    }

    //указываем от кого
    sprintf(buffer, "MAIL FROM: %s", login);
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize))
        return 1;

    //указываем кому
    sprintf(buffer, "RCPT TO: %s", rcpt);
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize))
        return 1;

    //и добавляем само сообщение (с параметрами)
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, "DATA", buffer, bufSize))
        return 1;

    sprintf(buffer, messageFormat, login, rcpt, subject, message);

    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize))
        return 1;

    //Прощаемся!
    send(sSocket, "QUIT", 4, 0);
    closesocket(sSocket);
    WSACleanup ();
    return 0;
}

bool SendSMTPCommand(SOCKET sock, const char* data, char* recvBuffer, int bufferSize)
{
    printf("Send: %s\r\n", data);
    int err = send(sock, data, (int)strlen(data), 0);
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    send(sock, "\r\n", 2, 0);

    *recvBuffer = 0;

    err = recv (sock, recvBuffer, bufferSize, 0); 
    if (err > 0)
    {
        recvBuffer[err] = 0;
        printf("Recv: %s\n", recvBuffer);
        return true;
    }

    printf("Receives error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return false;
}

//Функция из интернета, кто автор к сожелению не помню.
void base64_encode(char *out, const char *data, unsigned int len) {
    char *base64_set = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    unsigned char index2,index3;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(; i<len; (i+=3,data+=3,out+=4)) { 
        *out = base64_set[*data >> 2];
        index2 = (*data << 4) & 0x30;
        if(i+1<len) {
            index2 |= *(data+1) >> 4;
            index3 = ((*(data+1) << 4) & 0xFF) >> 2;
            if(i+2<len) {
                index3 |= *(data+2) >> 6;
                *(out + 3) = base64_set[*(data+2) & 0x3F];
            } else {                
                *(out + 3) = '=';
            }
            *(out + 2) = base64_set[index3];
        } else { 
            *(out + 2) = '=';
            *(out + 3) = '=';
        }
        *(out + 1) = base64_set[index2];
    }
    *out = 0;
}
```

[исходник + exe'шник](http://narod.ru/disk/60620167001.44e9c03b40fef9d3c2c2296665dd3764/smtp.rar.html)

Comment: **Нихрена себе у вас тут замес.**

Comment: Самому страшно, жуть :\

Comment: @lirik90, а ответы сервера анализировать не надо?

У Вас код программы вообще только для конкретного сервера, который **требует** AUTH и принимает AUTH LOGIN.

Я уже молчу, что в *очень* загруженной сети Ваша программа просто собъется, т.к. в начале получаемого по recv() буфера Вы можете запросто получить не код ответа на этот send(), а остаток ответа на предыдущий send().

Успешного дебага.

Comment: @avp, я очень рад что вы понимаете все плохость этого кода, значит строка текста прямо перед кодом определенно не вам! ;)

p.s. но все равно там даже есть целая проверище что на то чтобы сервер поддерживал "AUTH LOGIN"))

Comment: @lirik90, я действительно не слишком внимательно смотрел (уже 2 раза) код, но по прежнему мне кажется, что последовательность

    sprintf(buffer, "EHLO %s", domain);
    //отправляем EHLO yandex.ru
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, buffer, buffer, bufSize)) 
        return 1;
    //отправляем AUTH LOGIN
    if (!SendSMTPCommand(sSocket, "AUTH LOGIN", buffer, bufSize)) 
        return 1;

либо всегда отправит "AUTH LOGIN", либо прервет работу (`return 1;`).

Не так?

Comment: Мне очень стыдно что я произношу это, просто "набросанная" логика работает по пути наименьшего сопротивления, т.е. если сервер схавал SendSMTPCommand "AUTH LOGIN" значит он его поддерживает, в противном случае нет)) я к тому что хоть какая то, но проверка есть =))

Comment: @lirik90, я это к тому, что получив в ответ на 

    > AUTH ...
    < 500 Command unrecognized

можно работать дальше, а вот для

    > MAIL FROM ...
    < 530 5.7.0 Auth required

требуется аутентификация.

Answer (score 1):

Для заполнения адреса сервера я использую такую функцию

```
// avp 
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>

#ifdef WIN32
// gcc ... -lws2_32 -lwsock32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/socket.h>
#include  <netinet/in.h>
#include  <netdb.h>
#include  <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

/*
  make ip-addr & port in allocated struct sockaddr
  returns 0 - OK, 1 - unknown host, 2 - bad port (service) 
*/
int  
make_tcpservaddr (char *host, char *port, struct sockaddr_in *psa)
{
/* *psa an Internet endpoint address         */
  struct hostent      *phe;   /* pointer to host information entry    */
  struct servent      *pse;   /* pointer to service information entry */

  psa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  if (pse = getservbyname(port,"tcp"))
    psa->sin_port = pse->s_port;
  else if ((psa->sin_port = htons((unsigned short)atoi(port))) == 0) {
    return 2;
  }

  if (host == NULL || *host == 0 ||
      strcasecmp(host,"inaddrany") == 0 ||
      strcasecmp(host,"inaddr_any") == 0 ||
      strcasecmp(host,"255.255.255.255") == 0 ||
      strcasecmp(host,"0.0.0.0") == 0 ) 
    psa->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  else if (phe = gethostbyname(host))
    memcpy (&(psa->sin_addr),phe->h_addr, phe->h_length);
  else if ((psa->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host)) == INADDR_NONE) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0; // OK
}
```

Она заполняет struct sockaddr_in IP адресом и номером порта. Вызов:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
...
switch (make_tcpservaddr(host, port, &addr)) {
case 0:
   break; // OK
....
}
```

Далее Вы можете использовать структуру `addr` либо для соединения клиента с сервером

```
if (connect(cli_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
   perror("connect");
}
```

либо для сервера

```
if (bind(serv_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
  perror ("bind");
}
```

Очевидно обработка ошибок может быть другой. Например для сервера в случае errno == EADDRINUSE может быть предпринято несколько попыток bind()

**Относительно диалога по ESMTP/SMTP** (порт 25)

Во первых, всегда проверяйте код ответа сервера (первые 3 символа - код ответа). Если первый символ ответа 2 - то нормально.

Всегда проверяйте наличие слова ESMTP в приветствии сервера. Если его нет (сейчас это уже вряд ли можно увидеть, но все же...), то протокол SMTP, а не ESMTP. Для SMTP протокола Вы должны ответить строкой HELO, а для ESMTP - EHLO.

Вот пример (как видите login-password вовсе не обязателен. Его необходимость выявляется в ходе начального диалога с сервером)

```
220 mail.bigtelecom.ru ESMTP Postfix
ehlo scan.ru
250-mail.bigtelecom.ru
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 30720000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: avp@scan.ru
250 2.1.0 Ok
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Ну, тут читайте RFC для SMTP/ESMTP

Еще пара важных замечаний. Почтовый протокол *строкоориентированный*. Конец сроки это 2 символа \r\n. Но, некоторые клиенты (и возможно сервера) на практике пренебрегают символом \r (причем иногда). Это надо учитывать при разборе протокола.

Второе, тоже связано со строкоориентированностью. Функция recv() (к крайнему сожалению) может вернуть как часть строки, так и несколько строк. Поэтому получаемые данные Вам придется переводить в поток строк (ну или fdopen() сделайте (только в винде это странно работает - стимул бросить ее)).

Успехов. Спрашивайте если что еще про почту вспомню  - помогу.

Функции кодирования-раскодирования base64 с несколькими вариантами вызова из main (в #if ... #else ... #endif).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef WIN32
typedef unsigned char u_char;
#endif

/*
If the user agent wishes to send the userid "Aladdin" and password
   "open sesame", it would use the following header field:

      Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c

 */

/*
** Translation Table as described in RFC1113
*/
static const char cb64[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

// 3 bytes (len) to 4 base64 bytes
void
encode_b64block (u_char *in, u_char *out, int len)
{
  out[0] = cb64[in[0] >> 2];
  out[1] = cb64[((in[0] << 4) | (in[1] >> 4)) & 0x3f];
  out[2] = (len > 1) ? cb64[((in[1] << 2) | (in[2] >> 6)) & 0x3f] : '=';
  out[3] = (len > 2) ? cb64[in[2] & 0x3f] : '=';
}

/*
  Кодирует ilen байт в base64 
  Returns: количество байт, помещенных в b64out  (max oblen)
  в *ires количество закодированых байт из inpch8
 */
int
encode_b64 (u_char *inpch8, int ilen, u_char *b64out, int oblen, int *ires)
{
  int i, l = 0,
    bound = (oblen/4)*3; // байты входа, размещаемые в выходе
  if (bound > ilen)
    bound = ilen;
  bound = (bound/3)*3;
  for (i = 0; i < bound; i += 3, l += 4) {
    encode_b64block (inpch8+i, b64out+l, 3);
  }
  if (i < ilen) {
    if (oblen-l > 3) {
      int len = ilen-i;
      encode_b64block (inpch8+i, b64out+l, len);
      l += 4;
      if (len > 2)
    i += 3;
      else if (len > 1)
    i += 2;
      else
    i++;
    }
  }
  if (ires)
    *ires = i;
  return l;
}

static u_char decodetab[256];
static int    initdecode = 0;

// 4 (len) base64 bytes to 8-bit bytes. 
// Returns number of output bytes
int
decode_b64block (u_char *in, u_char *out, int len)
{
  if (len < 2 || in[0] == '=' || in[1] == '=' || in[0] == 0 || in[1] == 0)
    return 0;
  if (!initdecode) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
      decodetab[i] = 0xff;
    for (i = 0; cb64[i]; i++)
      decodetab[(u_char)cb64[i]] = i;
    initdecode = 1;
  }
  out[0] = (decodetab[in[0]] << 2) | (decodetab[in[1]] >> 4);
  if (len == 2 || in[2] == '=' || in[2] == 0)
    return 1;
  out[1] = (decodetab[in[1]] << 4) | (decodetab[in[2]] >> 2);
  if (len == 3 || in[3] == '=')
    return 2;
  out[2] = (decodetab[in[2]] << 6) | decodetab[in[3]];
  return 3;
}

// 4 (len) decodetab[] base64 bytes to 8-bit bytes. 
// Returns number of output bytes
int
decode_true_b64block (u_char *in, u_char *out, int len)
{
  if (len < 2)
    return 0;
  out[0] = (in[0]<<2) | (in[1] >> 4);
  if (len == 2)
    return 1;
  out[1] = (in[1]<<4) | (in[2]>>2);
  if (len == 3)
    return 2;
  out[2] = (in[2]<<6) | in[3];
  return 3;
}

// decode up to '=' or '\0' skipping "garbage"
// Returns output length
int
decode_b64str (u_char *inb64, u_char *out, int olmax, u_char **endinp)
{
  int  i, len = 0, bound = olmax-3, go = 1, l;

  if (!initdecode) {
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
      decodetab[i] = 0xff;
    for (i = 0; cb64[i]; i++)
      decodetab[(u_char)cb64[i]] = i;
    initdecode = 1;
  }

  u_char ib[4];
  while (go) {
    for (l = 0; l < 4;) {
      if (*inb64 == '=' || !*inb64) {
    go = 0;
    break;
      }
      if ((ib[l] = decodetab[*inb64++]) < 128)
    l++;
    }
    if (len < bound)
      len += decode_true_b64block(ib,out+len,l);
    else {
      u_char ob[3];
      int lb = decode_true_b64block(ib,ob,l);
      int lm = olmax-len;
      if (lm > lb)
    lm = lb;
      for (i = 0; i < lm; i++)
    out[len++] = ob[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (endinp)
    *endinp = inb64;
  return len;
}

// base64 encode a stream adding padding and line breaks
void 
b64_file_encode( FILE *in, FILE *out, int lsize, char *eol )
{
    u_char inb[3], outb[4];
    int i, len, blocks = 0;

    if (lsize < 1)
      lsize = 76;
    if (!eol)
      eol = "\n";

    while(!feof(in)) {
      len = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            inb[i] = getc (in);
            if (!feof(in)) {
                len++;
            }
            else {
                inb[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (len) {
            encode_b64block (inb,outb,len);
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                putc (outb[i],out);
            }
            blocks++;
        }
        if (blocks >= (lsize/4) || feof(in)) {
            if (blocks)
          fputs (eol,out);
            blocks = 0;
        }
    }
}

// decode a base64 encoded stream discarding padding, line breaks and noise
void
b64_file_decode (FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
  u_char buf[4097];
  int  l;

  while (fgets((char *)buf,4097,in)) {
    l = decode_b64str (buf,buf,4097,NULL);
    fwrite (buf,1,l,out);
  }

}

#if 0
main ()
{

  //  decode (stdin,stdout);
  u_char x = 0xf1;
  u_char y = (x>>4);
  char *in = "Ala";
  char out[10];
  out[4] = 0;

  int l = strlen(in);

  encode_b64block (in,out,l);

  printf ("%s\n",out);

  out[4] = ' ';
  out[9] = 0;

  l = decode_b64block (out,out+5,4);
  out[5+l] = 0;
  printf ("l = %d [%s]\n",l,out);

  char outp[100];
  u_char *last;
  int ls = decode_b64str ("  QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",outp,19,&last);
  outp[ls] = 0;
  printf ("decode_b64str %d <%s> [%c]\n",ls,outp,*last);

  char b64[100];
  int  ic, lb64 = encode_b64 (outp,ls,b64,100,&ic);
  b64[lb64] = 0;
  printf ("encode_b64 = %d <%s> %d\n",lb64,b64,ic);

}
#else
main ()
{
  char buf[1000];
#if 0
  while (fgets(buf,1000,stdin)) {
    int l = decode_b64str(buf,buf,999,NULL);
    write (1,buf,l);
  }
#else
  //  b64_file_decode (stdin,stdout);
  b64_file_encode(stdin,stdout,0,0);
#endif
}
#endif
```

Надеюсь будет полезным.

Comment: > Перенесенный код из коментов и удалены ошибки которые ну совсем в глаза бросились..

Пробовал компилировать код

    D:\CREATE~1\C__~1\Mail\mail.cpp: In function `int main()':
    D:\CREATE~1\C__~1\Mail\mail.cpp:17: request for member `resize' in `text', which is of non-aggregate type `char[1025]'
    Failure

Comment: @ananas, не совсем понял, но если насчет моей функции, то

    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -c ts.c
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ 
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ -c ts.c
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ 
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ --version
    g++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
    Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Как видите и g++ и gcc нормально воспринимают в Windows 7 MinGW. В линуксе тоже OK.

Вы в чем работаете?

Comment: > Это был комментарий для lirik90  

Пишу на c++ для консоли gcc.exe -v 2.95.2 19991024 под Windows XP

Comment: @ananas, попробуйте с winsock.h вместо winsock2.h (только это *не библиотеки, а файлы заголовков*, но суть не в названии). 

Возможно в Вашей версии (поставке) gcc все необходимые структуры и константы описаны там. Если нет, посмотрите, возможно среди Ваших "системных" инклюдников есть такие же, как для \*nix.

Answer (score 0):

## Перенесенный код из коментов и удалены ошибки которые ну совсем в глаза бросились..

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winsock.h>

int main() 
{ 
    WSADATA ws;

    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    hostent *d_addr;

    char text[1024 + 1];
    int result;

    text.resize(1024);

    char * cstr;
    string str1,str2,str3;

    //инициализируем сокеты 
    if (FAILED (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(1,1), &ws))) 
    { 
        printf("Error in WSAStartup(...)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //создаем сокет 
    s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) { 
        printf("Error in socket(...)\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //получаем адрес сервера 
    d_addr = gethostbyname ("smtp.yandex.ru"); 
    if (d_addr == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error in gethostbyname(...)\n"); 
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    };

    //заполняем параметры адреса 
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((unsigned long ) d_addr->h_addr); 
    addr.sin_port = htons (25);

    //устанавливаем соединение 
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == (connect (s, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr)))) 
    { 
        printf("Error in connect(...)\n"); 
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    }

    //ждем ответ от сервера 
    result = recv(s, text, 1024, 0); 
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error recv\n"); 
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    }

    text[result] = 0;
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    //приветствуем сервер 
    strcpy(text, "EHLO smtp.yandex.ru\r\n");
    send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", text);

    strcpy(text, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n"); 
    send(s, text, strlen(text), 0);

    //НУ И ЧТО ВЫ ЗДЕСЬ ОТПРАВЛЯЕТЕ ???
    strcpy(text,"логин в base64\r\n"); 
    send(s, text, strlen(text), 0);

    //и здесь "ЧТО ОТПРАВЛЯЕТЕ ???"
    strcpy(text, "пароль в base64\r\n"); 
    send(s, text,strlen(text),0);

    //ждем подтверждение от сервера 
    result = recv(s, text, 1024, 0); 
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error recv\n"); 
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    }

    text[result] = 0;
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    //сообщаем отправителя 
    str1 = "MAIL FROM: "; 
    cout << "mail otpravitelya: "; 
    cin >> str2; 
    str1 += str2; 
    str1 += "\r\n";

    send(s, str1.c_str(), str1.length(), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", cstr);

    //ждем подтверждение от сервера 
    result = recv(s, text, 1024, 0); 
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error recv\n"); 
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    }

    text[result] = 0;
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    //сообщаем получателя 
    str1 = "RCPT TO: "; 
    cout << "mail poluchatelya: "; 
    cin >> str3; 
    str1 += str2; 
    str1 += "\r\n";

    send(s, str1.c_str(), str1.length(), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", cstr);

    //ждем подтверждение от сервера 
    recv(s,text,sizeof(text),0);
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    //подаем команду, что готовы начать передачу письма 
    strcpy(text,"DATA\r\n");
    send(s,text,strlen(text),0);
    printf("send - %s", text);

    //ждем подтверждение от сервера 
    recv(s,text,sizeof(text),0);
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    //передаем заголовок

    //от кого письмо str1 = "FROM: ";
    cout << "mail otpravitelya: ";
    cin >> str2;
    str1 += str2; 
    str1 += "\r\n";

    //Тут чаго ???
    send(s, str1.c_str(), str1.length(), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", cstr);

    //кому письмо 
    str1 = "TO: ";
    str1 += str2; 
    str1 += "\r\n";

    send(s, str1.c_str(), str1.length(), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", cstr);

    //тема письма 
    str1 = "SUBJECT: ";
    cout << "Tema mail: ";
    cin >> str2;
    str1 += str2; 
    str1 += "\r\n\r\n";

    send(s, str1.c_str(), str1.length(), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", cstr);

    //текст письма 
    cout << "Text: ";
    cin >> str1;
    str1 += "\n";

    send(s, str1.c_str(), str1.length(), 0); 
    printf("send - %s", cstr);

    //говорим, что закончили 
    strcpy(text, "\r\n.\r\n");
    send(s,text,strlen(text),0);
    printf("send - %s", text);
    result = recv(s,text,sizeof(text),0);
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error recv\n"); 
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    }

    text[result] = 0;
    printf("recv - %s", text);

    //прощаемся с сервером  
    send(s,"QUIT", 4,0);
    printf("send - QUIT");

    //закрываем сокет 
    closesocket(s);

    //деинициализирует сервис 
    WSACleanup();

    printf("\n");
    printf("Press any key\n");
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну как минимум после recv было бы не плохо на ошибки проверять, да и что например если пароль не правильный или пользователя такого нет, по моему в примере выше мысль была наглядной...  а еще если на c++ пишите, то там такая прикольная штуковина есть, "классы" называется ;) раз уж так хочется побороть смтп клиент, слипите свой маленький класс, а то это имхо еще хуже читается чем мой пост выше))

Comment: Ооооо бррррр)))) как много new[] и как мало delete[] =)))))

Comment: recv(s,text,sizeof(text),0);  это что такое ? Вы проверяли что вам вернет sizeof(text)?) На самом деле вам бы какую нибудь книжечку прочитать =)

Comment: @ananas, ну как то все совсем плохо, хотя бы, сравните с "это" с вашим кодом "из коментов" и посмотрите из разницы чего совсем делать не надо )) Например если вы выделяете память char* var = new char[1024]; то нужно ее освобождать!!! и т.д......

Comment: >recv(s,text,sizeof(text),0);это что такое?Вы проверяли что вам вернет sizeof(text)?

В описании сказано оператор sizeof возвращает размер в байтах объекта или типа данных. Правильно ли я понимаю, в моем случае это размер массива символов в байтах, а в recv нужна длина буфера которая измеряется в количестве символов. Чтобы ф-я recv сама определяла кол-во символов в массиве text, нужно заменить на другую ф-ю, которая будет вычислять длину не в байтах, а в кол-ве символов? Как я понимаю, если ставить вручную эту цифру, при вводе более этого кол-ва символов будет ошибка из-за переполнения буфера

Comment: >На самом деле вам бы какую нибудь книжечку прочитать =)  

Читал
Д-р Сидни Фейт. TCP_IP Архитектура протоколы реализация
Крупник А.Б. Изучаем С++
Но без практики очень много непонятного.

Comment: @ananas, в данном случае байты и символы это одно и то же. 

    recv(сокет, адрес куда читать, максимум сколько байт, флаги)
      возвращает сколько РЕАЛЬНО прочел

Вы скажите, функции с base64 нужны? Если да, могу выложить в **update** моего ответа.

Comment: @avp  
Если не сложно выложите.

Comment: @ananas, выкладываю.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь за код в таком виде.

```
strcpy(text,"логин в base64\r\n");
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0);
```

В этом месте, свой логин перевожу в base64 программой, потом вставляю в код, компилирую. Да очень не удобно, для каждого адреса компилировать программу. Для пароля аналогично. Как раз хотел создать отдельный вопрос, чтобы в итоге логин и пароль вводить при подключении через консоль, а функция которая станет итогом, будет переводить текст из консоли в base64 и вставлять в указанное выше место.

Comment: В этом месте вы могли бы уже использовать функцию base64_encode из моего примера, вы вообще запускали его ? все что вам нужно, это скачать исходник открыть его в visual studio нажать в меню Проект->Свойства там перейти в отладка и в строке "Аргументы команды" поправить параметры командной строки в соответствии с вашей учеткой на смтп сервере;) , а потом (ЭТО ВАЖНО) нажать F11 и клацать F11 пока программа не завершится (в процессе периодически поглядывая в таблицу "Локальные"), и я почти уверен что после этого вам будет проще ))

Comment: Я и планирую использовать ф-ю base64_encode, но у меня пока нет работающей.
Ваш exe я запускал консоль появляется на 1с и исчезает, ничего не происходит.
исходник при компиляции выдает

D:\CREATE~1\C__~1\smtp\smtp.cpp:3: WinSock2.h: No such file or directory

т.к. у меня есть только библиотеки winsock, winsock2 нашел только для VS
Исходник только с void base64_encode выдает

d:\gcc\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\libmingw32.a(main.o)(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Comment: Исходник как я понял для VS, с ней я еще не работал, так как пробую писать на c++ для консоли gcc.exe -v 2.95.2 19991024, думаю чтобы не запутаться в 2 программах.